# Help Identifying hose

Tags: electrical, shed, landscaping

So  in the back of the property i'm currently  running direct burial cable to the shed,, while digging the trench i came across the hose pictured.
I know for a fact it has nothing to do with us,and nothing to do with the neighbours,it looks like copper but seems to be plastic..  should i dig it all up or just leave it where it is and don't give it a second thought?
(The misses thinks i should just dig it up and find out where it goes)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to [edit] your post and take another crack at including the picture. Also, use extreme caution when you encounter unknown things in the ground, especially pipes of any sort. Did you call 811 (or other local utility location service) before digging? If so, you should be able to eyeball a line of flags or colored paint on the ground to determine what kind of line this is. It definitely looks like copper pipe to me.

Comment: Copper is used quite often for water lines , could you get a good focused pic of the skinned area it could be a copper covered cable, is your cable feed on that side of the house? I would lean to cable but a clear photo might clear things up is it heading towards the property line possibly a pole or ~3foot tall utility connection point.

Comment: It's not very deep, should be easy to trace it by just plunging a hoe down into the ground every two feet or so.  With enough force to feel the pipe but not break it.  Or you may be able to trace it with a metal detector.

Comment: 811 was called when we moved our home onto the property( few years ago), but on this occasion , no. Its not the cable feed,i know where that is,also its not near any property lines.its kinda near  our well,but the well water line is a  bigger white PVC line.

Comment: I'd expect more corrosion on a copper line that had been buried for some time. How long has it been there, i.e. assuming no one has been tunneling under the property how long have _you_ been there? A buried hose would be likely to collapse, but flexible _engineered resin_ (aka plastic) tubing is common enough for irrigation and the like. A water line should be below the local frost line, if applicable. Do you know the appropriate depth for your area? Old fuel oil line to a buried tank?

Comment: I have no idea how long its been here,, we've been on the property for 3 years already,and before that the property  had another  mobile home on here.As mentioned it doesn't feel like copper at all, its feels more like plastic.,

Comment: Added a (hopefully ) more focused picture of the skinned area.We're in South Carolina,so we get little to no frost in the winter,

Comment: First few Google results for "copper colored plastic tubing" are for irrigation (drip tubes). May have been (mis)used as some kind of conduit? I don't see any labeling on the exposed tubing in the photos.

Comment: over the next few days ill dig and follow the line.

Comment: I would call 8-1-1 as Freeman suggested before you dig, prod, move or shovel anything!

Comment: The look and depth are consistent with irrigation drip line.  Does anyone nearby have a sprinkler system?  If it's drip line you should be able to find tiny holes in the pipe every few inches/feet.

Comment: We have a  irrigation system,we put in ourselves and only used a black  line, but  nowhere near where this is located.Calling 811 now after i have started the trench, would i be in any trouble? Also when  we called 811 when we moved the house ( few years ago),, they  didnt  flag anywhere where this cable is located.

Comment: You should have placed a ruler in the picture so we could see the size of the pipe.  You said there was a mobile home on the property?  See if the pipe ends there.

Comment: So, you've had all summer, did you figure out what this is?

Comment: nope,, in the end i didn't find out what it was,, to be honest i got caught up in other projects,, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Give it a squeeze, if it flexes then it is low pressure pipe (probably for irrigation). If you cut it, be careful in case it is being used as conduit.